# Flutter: How to make sure my team has the same formatting rules on VSCode and Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

My 2 partners use Android Studio while working on our Flutter app while I use VSCode. We ran into an issue that our pull requests often have a lot of extra junk in the form of constant whitespace reformatting between the two IDE's. Is there a way to make sure we all have the same formatting rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose either Husky and Lint-Stage or Lefthook for this purpose.

For using Lefthook see the documentation from this link (https://github.com/evilmartians/lefthook).

Checkout this post which I followed for staged files only with lefthook
(https://dev.to/arthurdenner/git-hooks-in-flutter-projects-with-lefthook-52n).

If you want to try Husky and Lint-Staged, follow this post (https://thisiscem.medium.com/boosting-code-quality-in-your-flutter-projects-lint-staged-and-husky-integration-4bcee79bbb85)